# Jquery drag and drop - add - delete

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I need to add deleted list(li) from "list-B" to "list-A"

is this possible?

My code

HTML:

```
<div id="list-A">     
  <ul id="sortable-left" class="connectedSortable mdm-left-sortable ui-sortable">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<div id="list-B">     
  <ul id="sortable-right" class="connectedSortable mdm-right-sortable clearfix ui-sortable">

  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
     $("#sortable-left, #sortable-right").sortable({
         connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
         receive: function(e,ui){
         }
     });

     $("#sortable-right").on("click", "li a", function () {
         $(this).closest('li').remove();
     });
```

Comment: So what's the issue..? what's not working..? do you want to drag items from b to a or something else..?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `a` inside `<li>item 1</li>`, so the function would never be called. So

**Instead of :**

```
$("#sortable-right").on("click", "li a", function () {
         $(this).closest('li').remove();
     });
```

**Try this:**

```
$("#sortable-right").on("click", "li", function () {//removed 'a'
         $(this).closest('li').remove();// or you can use:  $(this).remove();
     });
```